# Recommendations for Changing the Default Shell For Service Accounts

Tags: linux, hardening

It seems as if most Linux systems use either `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` as the default shell for service accounts. Many hardening guides, such as CIS benchmarks, recommend changing the default shell for these accounts to `/dev/null`. While many recommendations have an anslysis attached, this is one that I have never seen justified. What concerns are driving this recommendations and what threat it is attempting to mitigate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only true technical reason I'm aware of is the possibility of malicious file substitution.  Consider an attacker who finds a way to write to arbitrary files.  If they can overwrite /sbin/nologin or /bin/false with a copy of /bin/bash, then they can conceivably find a way to log in as a service user and continue to elevate their privilege from there.

However, /dev/null cannot be trivially replaced in such a manner, for various reasons:

- It's a device, not a flat file
- Anything written to it disappears, so a simple overwrite won't work
- If someone did replace it with /bin/bash, it might then in turn be overwritten by one of the many programs that use /dev/null as a bit sink, thwarting the attacker
- If someone did replace it, it could break some system functionality in a way that will alert the administrators that something is wrong, much more so than replacing 'nologin' or even 'false'.

There is also a non-technical reason, which is that many administrators are bound by tradition and/or the habits they learned long ago, and /dev/null was once a more common choice for this use (I'm pretty sure /sbin/nologin didn't exist 20 years ago).  Make of that what you will.

Comment: +1 The reason we were given aeons ago was exactly this - you can't overwrite /dev/null

Comment: That justification seems silly.  If the attacker can replace arbitrary files in /bin/, you are already totally hosed.  Moreover, it is simply outright wrong to say that /dev/null is easier to replace.  If you have permissions to write to /dev (namely, root permissions), then you can replace /dev/null with any file you like.  On my machine, the permissions needed to overwrite a file in /dev are exactly the same as the permissions needed to overwrite a file in /bin.  I think this claimed justification is completely bogus.

Comment: You are assuming the attacker logged in to replace files, but that is not the scenario I'm describing.  History is replete with examples of services (ftpd, httpd, what have you) being used to overwrite files but not granting any sort of interactive access or the ability to execute arbitrary commands.  Once the attacker has overwritten the file, they leverage that change to improve their access.

Consider the current 0-day Wordpress attack.  Use 'timthumb.php' to write an arbitrary php file to the web server, then execute it.  It's a classic pattern of access elevation.

Comment: (Oops, hit return too early).  As for permissions, "echo '' > /dev/null".  Good.  Now "echo '' > /bin/bash".  See the difference?

Comment: I agree with D.W. here. If you can overwrite `/sbin/nologin`, you can also overwrite `/etc/passwd`, or `/bin/login` or some other file with the same permissions but that is executed by root. For the last point: that's what tripwire is for.

Comment: Giles, this attack assumes full overwrite is possible but editing is not.  Overwriting /etc/passwd has the side effect of breaking every other user on the box which is highly noticeable.  Likewise, what local binary would you overwrite login with that would grant malicious access without being totally obvious (e.g., suddenly real users are logged straight in without password).

This attack scenario assumes file overwrite *without* local access.  Local access is needed for more finely grained changes such as passwd and login.  Replace a bogus shell, though, and there are less side effects.

Comment: I fail to understand your attack scenario. If a remote user has the ability to just overwrite, yes, he will not be able to overwrite /dev/null but he can easily upload a php shell and run commands if the webserver runs as root (rm /dev/null). And even simplier, if he can overwrite system files at will, he won't bother with /dev/null, he will overwrite the ssh daemon to allow him access or something. The login shell gets executed after authentication. Anyway, your answer is correct, this is the reason /dev/null is recommended - but I disagree with the recommendation itself.

Comment: John, you're right, there's a lot of play as far as what else an attacker could do with the same capabilities that would enable this attack.  As I say, some of the reason for /dev/null as the choice is tradition, and when this "best practice" was devised, there were no web servers, much less PHP.  Personally, I agree that this is a minor security improvement, and that the choice of nologin vs. null is a bit pedantic - but the question was, why is null suggested?  I've tried to answer with the historical context.

Comment: Looking back on this, I can see a difference: overwriting `/dev/null` breaks pretty much everything. Overwriting `/bin/nologin` is an easy stealthy backdoor.

Comment: I'm going to add that our *nix guru (as in, he's contributed to a book or two you likely have on your shelf) says:

"this is crap -
if someone has that level already they can replace dev null with a shell.
I've seen shells in compromised systems in /dev"

Comment: Scandalon, no one claimed you couldn't place a shell in /dev or even /dev/null - just that it's likely to be either noticed (if other programs rely on it and are broken) or overwritten (by other programs relying on it...)

Answer (score 4):

I'm no Linux guru, but if I compare this to recommendations for service accounts on Windows, I think this is comparable to removing all privileges, including the possibility for interactive logon.
This is probably just a question of minimizing attack surface / least privilege...:

> If you don't need it, shut it off.

Answer (score 4):

Great question!  As far as I know, there is no justification for this advice.  As far as I know, it is bad advice; `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` is just fine.  (If I've missed something, I look forward to learning what it is that I've overlooked.)

Answer (score 3):

Using /dev/null would result in no security audit log of an unauthorized interactive shell login attempt.

Comment: Hardening Linux By James Turnbull (2005) Chapter 1 page 21 is my source for this.  I'd imagine extra logging could be configured to catch login attempts even when the shell is /dev/null, but I don't think any distros give that logging out of the box.